# Why nic with incorrect subnet mask can still ping the gate way?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, iptables, subnet

At first, my network config was like this:

```
$ ip a
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:97:0e:bd:b1:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.66.65.2/24 brd 10.66.65.255 scope global em1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3e97:eff:febd:b168/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip r
default via 10.66.65.254 dev em1  proto static 
10.66.65.0/24 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.66.65.2  metric 1
```

in this way, the network subnet mask is incorrect. I don't have the access to internet but I can ping gateway 10.66.65.254.

Then I flush the route table and ip address of em1 and restart nic. And I have a new route table and ip:

```
$ ip a s dev em1
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:97:0e:bd:b1:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.66.65.2/23 brd 10.66.65.255 scope global em1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3e97:eff:febd:b168/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip r
default via 10.66.65.254 dev em1  proto static 
10.66.64.0/23 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.66.65.2  metric 1
```

and I can access the internet now.

What I think have happened before I change restart the nics is like:
the packet to the internet have a destination of say 172.1.1.1 and 10.66.65.2 as source, so it look up the route table and go out thought em1, then the gateway received the packet, but when the packet is going back to em1, the gateway cannot find an appropriate route entry for 10.66.65.2/24, so it dropped the packet, so I can't access the internet.

But I am wondering why I can ping the gateway, why is it able to send packet to me this time?

Thanks

Comment: It seems the question is incorrect, because it's quite normal that it is going to receive packet from the gateway since we are in the same subnet in it's option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mask was fine to start with, at least so far as contacting the gateway is concerned. In fact,  this line,

```
   inet 10.66.65.2/24
```

makes sure that your gateway and you belong to the **same** subnet, and in fact you *did* access your gateway, and got a response back. So the reason why you could not access the Internet is to be sought elsewhere. Two possibilities: 1) your gateway was off-line, 2) your DNS wasn't correctly set in /etc/resolv.conf.

However, please notice also that, after flushing your network information, the subnet you automatically receive from the DHCP, *10.66.65.0/23*, is **wider** than the above. It completely contains *10.66.65.0/24*, so that you were able to connect to your gateway even when you had the smaller subnet, **but** you missed out on the possibility to link to other machines in your LAN. So, besides correcting the file */etc/resolv.conf*, you may want to change the subnet to the wider, correct version. You can do it by invoking *DHCP* as follows:

```
ip link set dev em1 down
ip addr flush dev em1
ip link set dev em1 up
dhclient -v em1
```

The *-v* (= verbose) option prints to standard output the various steps of the negotiation with the DHCP server, but it is not available on all *dhclient* versions.

If instead you have a NIC with a static IP address, you can change the subnet as follows:

```
ip link set dev em1 down
ip addr flush dev em1
ip link set dev em1 up
ip addr add 10.66.65.2/23 dev em1
```

and that's it.

Comment: Since I can ping 8.8.8.8, it did seem to be a DNS problem

Comment: @dspjm Did you solve it? Do you need a hint? Let me know if I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm. Since it's not happening all the time, I need to check the next time I confront it.

Comment: @dspjm At any rate, next time it happens, edit (as sudo) the file /etc/resolv.conf, and add these two lines: nameserver 8.8.8.8, nameserver 8.8.4.4 This will solve such problems, the DNS servers above are Google's, often the fastest (they put their computers in ISP's centers all over the world, that's why).

Answer (score 3):

Host 10.66.65.2 with a /2**4** means it thinks 10.66.6**5**.0 through 10.66.65.255 are on the same subnet, so it would of course think that the router 10.66.65.254 was on its same subnet.

Host 10.66.65.2 with a /2**3** means it thinks 10.66.6**4**.0 through 10.66.65.255 are on the same subnet, so it would of course think that the router 10.66.65.254 was on its same subnet.

If the /23 subnet was  correct, it would have meant that some subnet broadcasts would've been mishandled by your host, and it would have meant that your host would have had to rely on the gateway to forward frames that it should have directly addressed to the 10.66.6**4**.x hosts. Or, more likely, the gateway would have sent *ICMP redirect* notices to your host, informing it that it could address those packets directly to their destination hosts at the link layer.

The subnet mask misconfiguration was probably not the source of your failure to get Internet connectivity.